# How to find the change set number of the memcached installation?

Tags: memcached

I have a working system that uses memcached (downloaded from http://www.codeplex.com/EnyimMemcached/). How do I find out the change set number from the files? (I can ask the person who installed it but she is no more with the company)

The `AssemblyInfo.cs` only lists the version number:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.2.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.2.0.0")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see their source code by going to:
http://enyimmemcached.codeplex.com/SourceControl/ListDownloadableCommits.aspx

According to that page, the tag was created in change #18026

Additionally, it looks like they have Subversion access, so to see a list of TAGS you could do:

```
svn list svn://host/tags
```